# Trying to plot data using networkx, and getting error about mapping nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, networkx

This is my first attempt at using networkx. Here is my sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'Circuit_Number': 1,'Description':'Stadium', 'Duration':10, 'Device_County':'Westchester', 'Picklist':1000, 'Postlist':50000}, 
       {'Circuit_Number': 2, 'Description':'Stadium', 'Duration':12, 'Device_County':'Westchester', 'Picklist':3000, 'Postlist':40000},
       {'Circuit_Number': 2, 'Description':'Arena', 'Duration':11, 'Device_County':'Westchester', 'Picklist':7000, 'Postlist':50000}, 
       {'Circuit_Number': 3, 'Description':'Arena', 'Duration':8, 'Device_County':'Westchester', 'Picklist':3000, 'Postlist':40000},
       {'Circuit_Number': 3, 'Description':'Casino', 'Duration':6, 'Device_County':'Queens', 'Picklist':5000, 'Postlist':6000}, 
       {'Circuit_Number': 4, 'Description':'Casino', 'Duration':20, 'Device_County':'Queens', 'Picklist':5000, 'Postlist':4000},
       {'Circuit_Number': 4, 'Description':'Library', 'Duration':15, 'Device_County':'Brooklyn', 'Picklist':5000, 'Postlist':9000},
       {'Circuit_Number': 5, 'Description':'Library', 'Duration':7, 'Device_County':'Brooklyn', 'Picklist':6000, 'Postlist':10000}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

######################################################################################

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 
# Input data files check
from subprocess import check_output
 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
 
G = nx.Graph()

    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_node(row['Circuit_Number'], group=row['Description'], nodesize=row['Duration'])
    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_weighted_edges_from([(row['Device_County'], row['Picklist'], row['Postlist'])])
    
def draw_graph(G,size):
    nodes = G.nodes()
    color_map = {1000:'#f09494', 3000:'#eebcbc', 5000:'#72bbd0', 6000:'#91f0a1', 7000:'#629fff'}
    node_color = [color_map[d['Duration']] for n,d in G.nodes(data=True)]
    node_size = [d['Duration']*10 for n,d in G.nodes(data=True)]
    pos = nx.drawing.spring_layout(G,k=0.70,iterations=60)
    plt.figure(figsize=size)
    nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=pos,node_color=node_color,node_size=node_size,edge_color='#FFDEA2')
    plt.show()

draw_graph(G,size=(30,30))
```

This is the error that I get:

```
node_color = [color_map[d['Duration']] for n,d in G.nodes(data=True)]

KeyError: 'Duration'
```

I am trying to feed rows from a dataframe into networkx, and produce a network graph, kind of like the one below, which I found online, but it's not plotting my data.

[image]

Comment: You renamed 'Duration' to 'nodesize' when adding the nodes.

Comment: Isn't the color a number? I'm a bit confused by this part: [color_map[d['Duration']]
How is this supposed to work?